# Htaccess remove string from URL behind last slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Looking for solution how to remove anything behind URL last slash.

example output URL:

```
http://example.com/pictures/123/category-name/
```

problems to avoid for this URL:

```
http://example.com/pictures/123/category-name/blah.html
http://example.com/pictures/123/category-name/blah/blah.html
http://example.com/pictures/123/category-name/blah/blah/blah.html
http://example.com/pictures/123/category-name/blah/
http://example.com/pictures/123/category-name/blah
```

So far i have this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/category-name/$ $1/$2/category-name/ [R]
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/category-name/(.*)$ category.php?VarA=$1&VarB=$2
```

it works for output URL and the URL with anything behind pattern. Problem is that it doesn't rewrite (redirect) to output URL if anything is behind last slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally use logic which is straight-forward like this:

```
#redirect to canonical url if no ending slash
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/category-name$ $1/$2/category-name/ [R,L]
#redirect to canonical url if anything behind slash
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/category-name/(.+)$ $1/$2/category-name/ [R,L]
#rewrite to PHP file if visiting the canonical url
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/category-name/$ category.php?VarA=$1&VarB=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Ultimater, i will test your solution. Extra question: if the output URL is the only one correct, should i use [R=301] instead of [R]?

Comment: I'd avoid permanent 301 redirects, since they can make debugging difficult due to browser caching issues, and if the domain ever does any kind of overhaul, you'll have to deal with users still redirecting due to caching issues. If something ever goes wrong, they'll be redirected somewhere unpredictable. During development, it's best to always use 302 temporary redirects. For production, I still prefer temporary 302 redirects since it means less to worry about if I ever have to touch the code. Permanent redirects are ok,  though, for sites serious about reducing their bandwidth usage.

Comment: p.s. `[R]` uses the default redirect which is a 302.

Comment: Are the [R] being indexed by search engines or not? This is more important factor to me.

Comment: Ultimater: Forgot to say - your solution works like charm :-) how much do i owe you?

Comment: Search engines will still index it but what gets indexed, the referring page or the destination page in the redirect, tends to vary on the search engine. Google I think uses whichever URL is less characters. See this article which compares the two: https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-discussing-302-redirects/